# Subclassing CALayer + Implicit Animation w/ Swift3

Tags: swift, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to implement "implicit animations" by overriding CALayer.  I've read through the documentation and find it rather complicated.  More over, I can't find any decent code examples, or internet posts explaining it well or using any Swift.

I've implemented by subclass `BandBaseCG` which attempts to provide implicit animation for property `param1`, and overridden `needsDisplay(forKey:)` which does get called once with my property where I return true.

But here is where it goes wrong.  My understanding is that I must return an object conforming to the `CAAction` protocol, say a `CABasicAnimation`, and this is what I do.  However, `action(forKey:)` or `defaultAction(forKey:)` do not get called with the `param1` key.

So I understand that at some point I can provide Core-Graphics drawing code in `draw(in ctx:)` to implement the actual implicit animation in response to some `layer.param1 = 2`.  But I just cannot get to this point because the API is simply not working how I expected.

Here is my current implementation:

```
import Foundation
import QuartzCore

class BandBaseCG: CALayer {

   @NSManaged var param1: Float

   override init(layer: Any) {

      super.init(layer: layer)

   }

   override init() {
      super.init()

   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }


   override func action(forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {

      print(event)

      if event == "param1" {

         let ba = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event)
         ba.duration = 2
         ba.fromValue = (presentation()! as BandBaseCG).param1
         ba.toValue = 2

         return ba
      }

      return super.action(forKey: event)
   }


   override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
      print("draw")
   }


   override class func defaultAction(forKey event: String) -> CAAction?     {

      if event == "param1" {

         let ba = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event)
         ba.duration = 2
         ba.fromValue = 0
         ba.toValue = 2

         return ba
      }

      return super.defaultAction(forKey: event)
   }

   override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {

      print(key)

      if key == "param1" {
         return true
      }

      return super.needsDisplay(forKey: key)
   }

   override func display() {
      print("param value: \(param1)")
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete working example (from my book):

```
class MyView : UIView { // exists purely to host MyLayer
    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
        return MyLayer.self
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {} // so that layer will draw itself
}
class MyLayer : CALayer {
    @NSManaged var thickness : CGFloat
    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == #keyPath(thickness) {
            return true
        }
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey:key)
    }
    override func draw(in con: CGContext) {
        let r = self.bounds.insetBy(dx:20, dy:20)
        con.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        con.fill(r)
        con.setLineWidth(self.thickness)
        con.stroke(r)
    }
    override func action(forKey key: String) -> CAAction? {
        if key == #keyPath(thickness) {
            let ba = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
            ba.fromValue = self.presentation()!.value(forKey:key)
            return ba
        }
        return super.action(forKey:key)
    }
}
```

You will find that if you put a MyView into your app, you can say

```
let lay = v.layer as! MyLayer
lay.thickness = 10 // or whatever
```

and that it will animate the change in the border thickness.

Comment: "More over, I can't find any decent code examples, or internet posts explaining it well or using any Swift." Okay, well I think that's a "decent" code example. As for the explanation, you clearly haven't read my book and that's not your fault. But it does exist and I think it explains all the parts of that code very well (just my opinion, of course).

Comment: i don't think that is fair.    I spent hours scouring the internet and found very little about this issue. As for your book, I'm very happy to find out about it and will certainly consult it in the future.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: Relax. I _said_ it wasn't your fault! No harm no foul. And I've given you the code, and you'll find it works (and there is a downloadable complete project behind it). We're on the same team here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pick up on the "tone".  Your right, its a great example and i appreciate it.  Specifically, it seems like the #keypath (which i didn't see mentioned in any of the tutorial i read through, and is a slightly obscure language feature) was the key functional difference I was needing, yeah?

Comment: it seems, though the line
`ba.fromValue = self.presentation()!.value(forKey:key)` is throwing `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.  This is just dragging the code into a file, and running the lay.thickness in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it would help to try downloading and running the actual project? It's here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch04p165customAnimatableProperty2

Comment: Oh, you said `viewDidLoad`? That makes no sense at all - never do that. You can't possibly do an animation in `viewDidLoad`; the view is not even in the view hierarchy yet. That is _way_ too soon to animate anything. Move it over to `viewDidAppear` and I think your problems will be over.

Comment: yeah, i switched the presentation()! to ? which saved the runtime error, but that does make a lot of sense to save it until viewDidAppear. I guess the presentation layer is nil at viewDidLoad time for reasons..I'm just running through the code in a blank project at the moment.  BTW, which of your books contains this CA stuff in it?

Comment: The big one (the second one). It has a chapter on Animation. — It wouldn't kill me to change the `!` to `?` in the original, but in a way I'd rather crash if I try to animate at an illegal moment. :)

Comment: Oh, i totally agree.  ! -> ? to supplement an edge case is a code smell, imo

Comment: Question about this code, why is @NSManaged used here instead of @dynamic? I thought NSManaged was only for CoreData objects.

Comment: @C0D3 You have to think of what Cocoa / Objective-C is doing behind the scenes. Swift is just a way of talking to it. So, Swift `@NSManaged` is Objective-C `dynamic`, meaning a setter/getter will be synthesized at runtime, and that's what we need here, just as in Core Data. See http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_making_a_property_animatable for the underlying Objective-C mechanism that is being "translated" into Swift here. (Swift `dynamic` is something else entirely.)

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks @matt